# Pass/Refer a SQL file in Apache Beam instead of string

Tags: python, sql, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, dataflow

I'm trying to run a simple Beam pipeline to extract data from a BQ table using SQL and push to a GCS bucket.

```
class SimplePipeline:
    def run_pipeline(self, known_args, pipeline_args, streaming_flag):
        pipeline_options = PipelineOptions(pipeline_args, streaming=streaming_flag, save_main_session=True)
        custom_options = pipeline_options.view_as(self.get_pipeline_options_class())
        log_info("Starting Pipeline")
        
        sql_query = "SELECT col1, col2, col3 FROM `project.dataset.table`"

        with Pipeline(options=pipeline_options) as pipeline:
            bq_source = beam.io.BigQuerySource(query=sql_query, use_standard_sql=True)


            apromore_event_schema = pa.schema([
                        pa.field("col1", "string",metadata={'parent':'id'}),
                        pa.field("col2", "string",metadata={'parent':'name'}),
                        pa.field("col3", "string",metadata={'parent':'age'})]
                    )

            process_data = (pipeline
                | "ReadFromBigQuery" >> beam.io.Read(bq_source)
                | "Write to Parguet" >> beam.io.parquetio.WriteToParquet(file_path_prefix='gs://project-gcs/test/',
                   schema=event_schema,file_name_suffix='.parquet')
            )
```

My requirement is to pass the SQL from a file (a simple .sql file) and not as a string. I want to modularize the SQL. So far, I've tried the following option - it did not work:

```
with open ("file_query.sql", "r") as myfile:
    sql_query = myfile.read()
```

where the contents of my *file_query.sql* file look like:
`` "SELECT col1, col2, col3 FROM `project.dataset.table`" ``

Any help on this folks?

Comment: The code seems to be correct, check if the full path of your SQL file is good.

A common issue in this case is passing a wrong absolute path for the file.

If the path is good, can you give more information on the error ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any information on the failure that you get? I ran almost a copy from what you shared, and it seems to work fine for me.

**file_query.sql**

```sql
SELECT * FROM `bigquery-public-data`.`baseball`.`games_post_wide`;
```

**pipeline.py**

```py
with beam.Pipeline(options=pipeline_options) as pipeline, \
    open("file_query.sql", "r") as file_content:
  sql_query = file_content.read()
  bq_source = beam.io.BigQuerySource(query=sql_query, use_standard_sql=True)

  (
      pipeline
      | 'ReadFromBigQuery' >> beam.io.Read(bq_source)
      | 'Print to Console' >> beam.Map(print)
  )
```

Running the above code is printing rows to the console.

Comment: Yeah, you're right. There was actually another issue with string representation.
Had to use `sql_query = myfile.read().replace("\n", "").replace("\'", "'")` to get rid of all forward slashes. 
I'm also using parameterized queries so needed `sql_query.format(table=table)`
Anways, thanks for confirming bud!