# How to pass sql from a .sql file in apache beam using java. The code works fine if I pass sql as a string in .withQuery()

Tags: java, jdbc, apache-beam, google-cloud-spanner

I am bit new to apache beam and I am writing code to connnect to spanner and execute a sql query using apache beam. Currently passing the query as .withQuery(spnQuery) under .apply method. spn query is defined as a string

I am not finding a method to read query from .sql in apache beam using java. I saw a similar problem solved using apache beam in another post using python ([Pass/Refer a SQL file in Apache Beam instead of string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73476487/pass-refer-a-sql-file-in-apache-beam-instead-of-string))

Comment: Can't you write could to read the sql file and provide the read content as a String to apache beam?

Comment: @user21615028 I proposed you a solution. Can you check it please and indicate us if it helps you to solve your issue ?

Answer (score 0):

You can read a sql file from resource folder.

Example of structure in your `Java` project (example with `BigQuery` but the principle is the same with `Spanner`):

```
your-project
    src
       main
           java
       resources
           bigquery
              queries
                   your-query.sql
```

Example of `SQL` query file with a parameter:

```sql
SELECT * FROM `@table`;
```

In the `Java` code, I use a library to read more easily the content of `SQL` file as `String`.

Add this dependency in your `pom.xml` `Maven` file :

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
    <version>2.11.0</version>
</dependency>
```

An example of `Java` code with `Beam` :

```java
import com.google.api.services.bigquery.model.TableRow;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.io.gcp.bigquery.BigQueryIO;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.transforms.PTransform;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.values.PBegin;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.values.PCollection;
import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;

public class YourClass {

    public PTransform<PBegin, PCollection<TableRow>> read() {
        String queryFilePath = "bigquery/queries/your-query.sql";
        String query = toStringContent(queryFilePath)
                .replace("@table", "table");

        return BigQueryIO
                .readTableRows()
                .fromQuery(query)
                .usingStandardSql();
    }

    private String toStringContent(String resourceFilePath) {
        InputStream inputStream = YourClass.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(resourceFilePath);

        try {
            return IOUtils.toString(inputStream, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Error while reading resource file", e);
        }
    }
}
```

- The method `toStringContent` load the content of `SQL` file from resource folder, using `commons-io` lib
- After retrieving the string content, I can replace params with `replace`
- I used `BigQueryIO` for this example but the principle is the same for `SpannerIO`

Comment: You’re welcome, this answer helped you to solve your issue ? If if it’s the case, can you upvote and mark it as solved please ?